# ¿Qué tanto me afecta si abrí un archivo .ora con bloc de notas y ahora todos me salen para abrir con este?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Esque abrí el archivo tnsnames.ora para hacer la conexión con visual, pero olvide copiarlo en otro lado y ahora todos los archivos .ora me salen para abrirlos con el bloc de notas. ¿Eso afectará mi cuando haga la conexión o a mi base de datos? ¿Cómo lo puedo arreglar?

Answer (score 3):

No estimado(a), el hecho de que cambies un programa predeterminado no afecta en nada su compilación o uso de otros programas mientras mantenga su extensión. Ahora si quieres cambiar los programas predeterminados puedes usar el siguiente [link](https://support.microsoft.com/es-cl/help/4028161/windows-10-change-default-programs) como guía.

**EDIT** 
Dejo ademas un método de como quitar un programa predeterminado de tus archivos.

**¿Cómo eliminamos una asociación de un tipo de archivo con un programa en Windows?**

Abierto Editor del registro (regedit)
a continuación, vaya a `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`
a la izquierda, bajo la clave `FileExts`, identificando sitios de subclave y sus extensiones archivos para los que quieren eliminar asociación predeterminada y eliminarlos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, vaya a `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` y limpiar si hay sitios de subclave con extensiones esos archivos.

Reiniciar y listo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Saludos